# Multi-gpu allocation through another function

Tags: pointers, cuda

Using CUDA, I want to allocate memory for different arrays, one for each GPU from a different function than main(), but I must have missed something in regard to pointer arithmetic. Here's what I thought,

```
void InitThisMemory(int***, int N, int Nout, size_t* pitch, int height, int width); // This function's purpose is to initialize A and the pitch

int main(void){
   int** A;
   int N = 10; 
   int NOut = 2;
   int height = 2, width = 2;
   size_t pitch;
   InitThisMemory(&A, N, NOut, &pitch, height, width);
   return 0;
}

InitThisMemory(int ***A, int N, int Nout, size_t* pitch, int height, int width){
  int i;
  *A = (int**)malloc(Nout * sizeof(int*));
  for(i = 0;i < Nout;i++){
      cudaSetDevice(i);
      cudaMallocPitch((void**)&(*A[i]), &(*pitch), width, height);
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: Not my actual code but this should reproduce the error. Let me know if I missed an allocation of a variable somewhere.

Why do I think that the problem is in the arithmetic? Simply because this works pretty well if `Nout = 1` (which means that I am using only one device).

Any ideas?

Comment: `for(i = 0;i < Nout)` --- haven't you forgotten to increment `i`? And how do you pass `width` and `height` to `InitThisMemory`?

Comment: yes, of course. Thanks for that.

That was fixed also. This code was written directly in the browser and kind of fast, so excuse me for anything "trivial" that I missed.

Comment: What *exactly* does work/not work mean in this question? Are you getting API errors? What are the symptoms of "not working"?

Comment: One main symptom : I get a segmentation fault immediately as soon as i = 1 for Nout = 2. It's like I'm not writing at the second pointer to and *int but to something else.

Comment: Ummm... `&(*pitchDev)`? How about `!!true`? Besides, I don't see the definition of `pitchDev` anywhere -- does it compile?

Comment: Fixed. I've been very careless on this question. Thanks for the effort to understand, everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bug, I think, is writing `(void**)&(*A[i])` instead of `(void **) (&(*A)[i])`, but I recommend you refactor as follows:

1. use a local int ** variable to hold the `malloc()` return value;
2. use that local in your call to `cudaMallocPitch()`;
3. pass back the `malloc()` return value only if all `cudaMallocPitch()` calls succeed.

If you do these things, then it will be simpler to write correct cleanup code in the event that one of the `cudaMallocPitch()` calls fails, and you needn't propagate the passback unless everything has succeeded.

Comment: You sir just made my day. That was it! 

Now about writing the code like this, I would really be interested to know if the problem is a) the absence of error checking or b) trying to do things in the most complicated, sure to create errors, way. 

If it's (a), then as stated, this is just a code that I wrote directly in the browser which, in my opinion, reproduces the memory error. The original code checks everything out before InitThisMemory returns. If it's (b) ... well, you are right, I guess. 

Thanks for sharing your experience of course! I will keep that in mind.

Comment: (a) and (b) are interrelated.  It is easier to write code that correctly checks for errors, if you write simpler code.  There's no performance benefit to inlining the indirection as your code sample does, so it's all downside (loss of clarity) and no upside. Consider also, if you were passing back an allocated structure pointer, then you'd have to parenthesize the passback every time you dereferenced it (i.e. (*p)->member not p->member).  Better to use a local, then pass it back. As for the error handling, it is probably best implemented here using goto, but that's another topic.